# Can't find name of parent model even when inside of nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a child by my nested form and I know the routes work because I'm on it.

```
resources :surveys do
  resources :questions
end
```

I selected the first survey to add questions too and than I want to display the name of the survey on the page:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @Survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @question = Question.new
  end
end
```

**http://localhost:3000/surveys/1/questions/new**

```
<div><%= @survey.name %></div> # show this

<div>
 <%= simple_form_for(@question do |f| %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Done" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

This gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SurveysController#new

Couldn't find Survey without an ID

app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:7:in `new'

{"survey_id"=>"1"}
```

Why? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what the error is telling you. If you want to find the "parent" model by id, you need to use `*parent*_id`, so in this case that would be:

```
@Survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
```

The `id` param is reserved for the *current* controller, which in this case refers to the id of a *question*, not a *survey*.